# INT(5) vs SMALLINT(5): numbers in parenthesis after the numeric type

Tags: mysql, datatypes

In MySQL table definitions is there a different between `INT(5)` and `SMALLINT(5)`?  Or do they both represent the same size?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[An `int` and a `smallint` have different sizes and consequently ranges.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)
The `(5)` is `smallint(5)` or `int(5)` is called a ["Numeric Type Attribute"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) and it represents the "display width" of the field,

> MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, `INT(4)` specifies an `INT` with a display width of four digits. This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. (That is, this width is present in the metadata returned with result sets. Whether it is used or not is up to the application.)
>
> When used in conjunction with the optional (nonstandard) attribute `ZEROFILL`, the default padding of spaces is replaced with zeros. For example, for a column declared as `INT(4) ZEROFILL`, a value of `5` is retrieved as `0005`.

This is a MySQL "extension", and zerofill is an "extension" on an extension.

For the sane method of controlling the display of a numeric type, don't ues Numeric type Attributes and instead use

- [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)
- [`LPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)
- [`RPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Comment: This attribute is mandatory in MySQL Workbench. What happens if I have the number 5000 and a data type `SMALLINT(1)`? Does the number 5000 get truncated to one digit? Which digit?

Comment: What is the name of this MySQL extension for display width, please?