# What is the difference between int(8) and int(5) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

I found out, that if you have a field defined as INT(8) without ZEROFILL it will behave exactly as INT(5)

in both cases the maximum value is

```
−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, from −(2^31) to 2^31 − 1
```

or do i miss something?

I found this Question:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/370/12923

> The (5) represents the display width of the field. From the
>   [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), it states:
>
> > The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column
> >     display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column
> >     specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to
> >     32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are
> >     displayed in full using more than three digits.
>
> The display width, from what I can tell, can be used to left-pad
>   numbers that are less than the defined width. So 00322, instead of
>   322. TBH, I've never used it.
>
> But it doesn't affect the storage size of the column. An int will take
>   up more space than a smallint.

so there seems to be no difference then.

Comment: so I assume, I am right here: **there is no difference**. Only if I would use ZEROFILL, there would show a different behaviour in smaller numbers

Answer (score 0):

See [12.2 Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) (MySQL Reference Manual)

Essentially what you listed is the max value for `INT` and not `BIGINT`.

- `INT(8)` is the equivalent of typing `INT` with a display width of 8 digits
- `INT(4)` is the equivalent of typing just `INT` with 4 display lengths.

The range of `BIGINT` is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 or 0 to 18446744073709551615.